# The background of div does not fill whole div after changing the way of displaying of divs that are in that div with help of JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I perform the inception of particular landing website that consists of 14 groups accordingly layout.

In the third group of that layout there are there columns descibed in the code as divs, every of which contains image, h3 and some text. The columns must be displayed one by one in the horizontal row if the width of the screen is 768px or higher. In case if this width is lower, these columns should be localted in the vertical row. It means the second must be lower than the first, and the third - lower than the second.

At this moment everything about the columns works normal. Especially, after some Javascript code manipulations. But also the background of the third group is pink and should cover whole space wherein these columns are located, no matter vertically or horizontally. But if the width of the screen is 768px or higher because of unknown reason the necessary div is not filled fully, but only the upper part. If the width of the screen witnesses that the device is a phone, than everything's displayed correctly.

```js
let width = screen.width;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("column-G3");
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("column-G3-outside");
    if(width<768)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            y[i].style.width = "100%";
            x[i].style.width = "100%";
        }
    }
    else if(width>=768)
    {
        width*=0.85;
        width_block = Math.floor(width*0.3);
        margin_block = (width - width_block*3);
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            x[i].style.width = width_block + 'px';
            x[i].style.display = "block";
            x[i].style.marginLeft = "auto";
            x[i].style.marginRight = "auto";
            y[i].style.float = "left";
            y[i].style.width = "33%";
        }
    }
```

```css
.G3
{
background: #a914b5;
background-size: cover;
font-size: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 5vw;
padding-top: 5vw;
}

.G3 p
{
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
}

.center-in-G3
{
width: 100%;
}

.center-in-G3 img
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.center-in-G3 h3
{
text-align: center;
}

.column-G3
{
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="G3">
    <div class="align-center">
        <div class="column-G3-outside">
            <div class="column-G3">
                <div class="center-in-G3">
                    <img src="./images/3/Icon.png">
                    <h3>New Music</h3>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column-G3-outside">
            <div class="column-G3">
                <div class="center-in-G3">
                    <img src="./images/3/Icon.png">
                    <h3>New Group</h3>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column-G3-outside">
            <div class="column-G3">
                <div class="center-in-G3">
                    <img src="./images/3/Icon.png">
                    <h3>New Themes</h3>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use with `display: grid;`? It will work way more easy and better. There are lots of sites to make a grid and receive the code from the grid that you made.